# How to implement transparent proxy on OS X?

Tags: mac, transparent-proxy, isolation

I run Tor on my MacBook Air, which has two interfaces: USB Ethernet Adapter and Wifi. I want to use my MacBook as transparent proxy so that it can share the Tor connection through Wifi for cell phones.

I follow the instructions on [TransparentProxy](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TransparentProxy), but failed. For Linux systems it’s easy to make an anonymizing middlebox that I have pasted test with virtual machine. But for OS X, the Tor client didn’t implement transport and only supports NATDPort.

Is that NATDPort the same as Transport? It seems not because it does not work when I used the NATDPort instead of Transport. So is there any method to implement that?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to use the transparent proxying features with modern OS X. Apple removed ipfw (which is what natdport would use), and doesn't provide headers for pf so Tor can't reliably use it and disables the feature while building.